# SolidWorks EPDM GetVar for BoM not working in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, solidworks

This one has me really stymied and I suspect it because I am now too "close" to the problem. I am converting a VB.NET routine into a VBA routine. Here is the VB.NET code that works as expected.`

```
    Dim rows() As Object
    BOM.GetRows(rows)
    Dim row As IEdmBomCell
    For Each row In rows
        If IsNothing(row) Then Exit For
        Dim rowString As String = row.GetTreeLevel.ToString & vbTab
        Dim varVal As String = ""

        For Each column As EdmBomColumn In columns
            row.GetVar(column.mlVariableID, column.meType, varVal, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
            If IsNothing(varVal) Then varVal = ""
            rowString = rowString & varVal & vbTab
        Next
        '-----------------------------WRITE THE ROW TO THE FILE 
        sw.writeline(rowString)
    Next`
```

The VBA code I have looks like this:

```
Dim varVal As String
Dim rows() As Variant
Dim row As IEdmBomCell
Dim rowstring As String

Call BOM.GetRows(rows)

    For p = 0 To UBound(rows)
        Set row = rows(p)
        If IsEmpty(row) Then Exit For
            rowstring = row.GetTreeLevel & vbTab
            varVal = ""

           For i = 0 To UBound(columns)
                column = columns(i)
                Call row.GetVar(column.mlColumnID, column.meType, varVal, Nothing, "", True)
                rowstring = rowstring & varVal & vbTab
                Debug.Print rowstring
            Next
            '-----------------------------WRITE THE ROW TO THE FILE
           sw.writeline (rowstring)
    Next
```

Where I am getting the failure is line `Call row.GetVar(column.mlColumnID, column.meType, varVal, Nothing, "", True)`.

The varVal variable never returns a value, yet the code is stepping through each column data set.

The VBA watch window for all the variables being worked on.

[image: Here is the VBA watch window for all the variables being worked on.]

I would like to place the blame on the row.GetVar call being broken, but the .NET code works just fine (on the same machine as the VBA). I just must have a bad assignment somewhere. Again, the code does not fail to run or generate any errors it just never creates the output expected, which looks like this:

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected Output]

VS. this is this result:

**Results of current code:**

[image: Results of current code]

Comment: While I can't give you a definitive answer, I strongly suspect that this has to do with the fact that SolidWorks discontinued VB6 support for its PDM API in 2008. I have tested your VB.NET code in a PDM test add-in I have and it works fine. As far as I can tell the codes are identical in terms of function. See the [2008 SolidWorks PDM API Release Notes](http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/epdmapi/ReleaseNotes-epdmapi.html#2008). The first item under "New and changed functionality" - "VB6 is no longer supported".

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but I ran into that issue as well. I've got it working in VBA using a Variant instead of a String variable.

So instead of
`Dim varVal As String`
try
`Dim varVal As Variant`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging around the API documentation, I am now fairly confident that the problem is in fact VBA itself.

This [information](http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/sldworksapiprogguide/Overview/Controls,_Visual_Basic_6.0,_and_Windows_XP.htm?id=26586cf01b424de7a21511134977e5db#Pg0&ProductType=&ProductName=) has been in the SolidWorks API documentation for a few versions now. It seems they recommend against using VBA in SolidWorks API applications, and confirm that using VBA may result in unexpected behavior.

I already linked this in my comment, but for completeness sake, [here](http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/epdmapi/ReleaseNotes-epdmapi.html#2008) is the first place in the release notes they confirm VBA (VB6) is not supported.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I have not had issues in the past, but that doesn't mean that there wouldn't be going forward. I am going work on it a bit more, but it does not seem like its fixable.

Comment: Following up because I'm interested - did you ever get the sample to work in VBA? If so, what did you have to do?

Comment: Nothing I have done yet has worked. Still going to look at it some more in a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with using the PDM API from VBA before and what I needed to do was create a [COM wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-create-wrappers-manually) to expose what I needed.